# Doing a heatmap on ggmap in R based on % and not line entries

Tags: r, ggmap

I have a [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KYpeWd0A76FynCxW6A1Xz1iYwx9SpIO3/view?usp=sharing) with the ff columns: (1) *latitude* of locations; (2) *longitude*; (3) *population_count*; (4) *sample_count*; (5) *sample_perc* (sample/ pop).

I need to visualise the sample_perc (col 5) over the ggmap output of the city as a heatmap. The problems I'm encountering are:

- Not all coordinates in the map are relevant, and hence do not have data
- Heatmap (geom_density) uses entries (rows) in the data and can't do aggregate (as far as I know)

Code:

```
amsmap <- get_map(location="amsterdam", zoom=14)

ggmap(amsmap) + 
      geom_density2d(data = dummy$sample_perc, 
        aes(x =request_lng, y = request_lat), size = 0.3) + 
      stat_density2d(data = dummy$sample_perc, 
        aes(x = request_lng, y = request_lat, fill = ..level.., 
        alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01, bins = 16, geom = "polygon") + 
      scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") + 
      scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)
```

> error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor

How can I successfully do this? Help please.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show the code you tried.

Comment: Added more info

Comment: Please provide inline data via e.g. `dput`, not a temporary Google drive link! Thanks.

Comment: Your first problem is that the `data` argument to `geom_density2d` should be a data frame, not a `factor`, as the error is telling you. So you want `data = dummy`, assuming dummy is your data frame with columns `request_lat`, `request_lng`.